# Bots don't access Metatags and Open Graph

Tags: next.js, seo, metadata, facebook-opengraph

We have a huge issue on our website, bots don't seems to find access to our metatags and opengraph wheareas we have some on our website when we inspect our code.

We have no "no-follow" tags.

Our header on theoffline.fr :

```html
<head><link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com"><link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin="true"><link rel="stylesheet" data-href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Public+Sans:wght@400;500;600;700&amp;display=swap"><script type="text/javascript" id="hs-script-loader" async="" defer="" src="//js-eu1.hs-scripts.com/25053800.js"></script><link href="/font/medium/made-mirage-medium.css" rel="stylesheet"><link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin=""><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"><meta name="robots" content="index,follow"><meta name="googlebot" content="index,follow"><meta name="description" content="Réservez facilement un break ou weekend réussi en Europe grâce à nos destinations, vols et hôtels triés sur le volet."><meta property="og:title" content="On part en weekend ?"><meta property="og:description" content="The Offline permet de réserver simplement des breaks réussis"><meta property="og:image" content="https://res.cloudinary.com/thiago9li214/image/upload/w_600/v1637599694/metaimage_home.png"><meta property="og:image:alt" content="home cover"><meta name="next-head-count" content="9"><noscript data-n-css=""></noscript><script defer="" nomodule="" src="/_next/static/chunks/polyfills-a40ef1678bae11e696dba45124eadd70.js"></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/webpack-c1b484df1c4f738003fb.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/main-c4f2541b93e4ae8b71f8.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app-45bf83b2e82b8ad55168.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/2c796e83-5c2bd38f513cac1a72df.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/493-0bf2abc775dda38e9783.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/962-5e3c0ea702c4b2b26f61.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/294-7bbb51a7ddd830e6cbcd.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/419-6b0210b57b5a60af5115.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/index-d8a59dfbac10e5b77106.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/ZM4D0O7c_ysUL_ZkSKtqG/_buildManifest.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/ZM4D0O7c_ysUL_ZkSKtqG/_ssgManifest.js" defer="">
```

What Facebook bot is finding (from the debugger):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link href="/font/medium/made-mirage-medium.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin="true">
<link rel="stylesheet" data-href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Public+Sans:wght@400;500;600;700&amp;display=swap">
<script type="text/javascript" id="hs-script-loader" async="" defer src="//js-eu1.hs-scripts.com/25053800.js"></script><link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<meta name="next-head-count" content="2">
<script defer nomodule="" src="/_next/static/chunks/polyfills-a40ef1678bae11e696dba45124eadd70.js"></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/webpack-c1b484df1c4f738003fb.js" defer></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js" defer></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/main-c4f2541b93e4ae8b71f8.js" defer></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app-45bf83b2e82b8ad55168.js" defer></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/2c796e83-5c2bd38f513cac1a72df.js" defer></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/493-0bf2abc775dda38e9783.js" defer></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/962-5e3c0ea702c4b2b26f61.js" defer></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/294-7bbb51a7ddd830e6cbcd.js" defer></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/419-6b0210b57b5a60af5115.js" defer></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/index-d8a59dfbac10e5b77106.js" defer></script><script src="/_next/static/ZM4D0O7c_ysUL_ZkSKtqG/_buildManifest.js" defer></script><script src="/_next/static/ZM4D0O7c_ysUL_ZkSKtqG/_ssgManifest.js" defer></script><style data-
```

Any ideas of what the problem might be?

Comment: How are you adding that to head? On a normal browser too, I am not getting your said tags in the source. My guess is you are adding them using some client side script. Either use `next/head` or modify your `_document` file. To reduce some effort you can directly use this plugin: https://github.com/garmeeh/next-seo

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding the following code to your `robots.txt`:

```
User-agent: facebookexternalhit
Disallow:
```

You would also have to check if you forbid some of the bots via your `robots.txt`

Comment: It's not only Facebook but every bot like Google, metatags.io... 
Our robots.txt seems clean :

User-agent: *
Sitemap: https://theoffline.fr/sitemap.xml

Comment: Google bot takes some time to scrape the content, it can take from a day or two to weeks depending on the content if you have added your sitemap to your Google Search Console. By the looks of it I can see that og tags are working as expected and are pulled from Facebook/Meta currently: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.theoffline.fr